# MySQL counter for specific situations

Tags: mysql, increment, auto-increment

I need to generate unique "ids", the catch is, it can be only between 1 - 99999.

The "good" thing is, that it has to be unique only in group with another column.

We have groups, each group has its own "group_id" and each group need something like `unique('group_id', 'increment_id')`

The 99999 records is enough for several years for each group right now, but it is not enough for all groups together, therefore I cant just create table with AUTO_INCREMENT and inserting there records and taking its auto increment.

For example, if I need 5 records for Group one and three records for Group two, I suppose to get something like this:

```
group_id, increment_id
1, 1,
1, 2,
1, 3,
1, 4,
1, 5,
2, 1
2, 2,
2, 3
```

Also, the conflict is not an option, therefore using something like "length" can be tricky, if done programatically (there can be i.e. 10 requests at once, each of them first select length for given group_id and then tries to create 10 rows with same increment_id)

However I am thinking - if I set it up as the value of subselect of count, than it will always be "ok"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a auxiliar table named counters to manage that:

table: counters
columns: group_id, current_counter

OR

Each time you insert a row increment_id = select max(increment_id)+1 from table_xxx where group_id = group_xxxx

Comment: The first option does not work itself - it would rise everytime I put record there, therefore reaching 99999 much sooner

Comment: However the second options - what about collisions? If lot of concurrent requests come to database to create such records, would it be always "ok", or it can crash because selecting "max" at given time is not max anymore when trying to put new record in?

Comment: you need to update the current_counter only for the specific group_id, each group will have separated counters as you wish.

Comment: myisam engine will perform in sequence inserts, about innodb im not so sure. but i think the database will protect new inserts in parallel because you are also performing a select on this insert, not 100% of that. Wich engine you are using?

Comment: Well if possible I would be really independent as much as possible to the current engine, but I suppose this is something that cannot be solved at "abstract level". We are currently using MariaDB, probably default settings, which is XtraDB

Answer (score 1):

You can use user variables to get the incrementing number within each group_id:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    @rn := if(@group_id = group_id,
                @rn + 1,
                if(@group_id := group_id, 1, 1)
            ) increment_id
from (
    select group_id
    from your_table t
    /* some where clauses */
    order by group_id
    ) t
cross join (
    select @rn := 0,
        @group_id := - 1
    ) t2
```